# Button click event not working in Titanium

Tags: button, ios6, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium appcelerator programming.My doubt is button click is event is working well in first screen after that when I click that button go to second screen.Second screen consisting of one button ,when I click that button it navigates to third screen .But button click event is not working in second screen.

I wrote the same code in two screens as follows:

Please tell where I did mistake.

First Screen:

```
Ti.include("Files/MainScreen.js");
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  title:'My Window',
  backgroundColor:'#cccccc'
});
win.open(); 

var itemView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    title:'',
    backgroundImage:'splash.png',
    height:'768',
    width:'1024'
});

// Eventlistener
itemView.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

   var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        background : "#000",
        title : "Image View",
        url:"Files/MainScreen.js"
    });
    newWindow.open(win,{animated:true}); 
});
win.add(itemView);
win.orientationModes=[Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT];
win.open();

MainScreen.js:

Ti.include("CustomerScreen.js");
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  title:'My Window',
  backgroundColor:'#cccccc',
  leftNavButton:btnCancel
  });

  var btnCancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Cancel'
});
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'main_screen.png'
});
win.add(image);
win.open();

var custbutton=Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'customer',
    top:200,
    bottom:300,
    left:90,
    height:'235',
    width:'235',
    backgroundColor:"#000"
});
custbutton.addEventListener('click',function alertingcustomer () {
var newWindow1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        background : "#000",
        title : "",
        url:"Files/CustomerScreen.js"
    });
   newWindow1.open(win,{animated:true}); 
});

win.add(custbutton);
win.open();


CustomerScreen.js
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  title:'Window',
  backgroundColor:'#cccccc',
  modal:true
});
win.open();
```

Comment: post u r entire code, let me see it....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I have created a sample application from your code. Try it out

**app.js**

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  title:'My Window',
  backgroundColor:'#cccccc'
});

var itemView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    title:'Splash screen',
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    height:'768',
    width:'1024'
});

// Eventlistener
itemView.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
   var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        background : "#000",
        title : "Image View",
        url:"MainScreen.js",
        backgroundColor:'#cccccc',
        leftNavButton:btnCancel
    });
    newWindow.open(win,{animated:true}); 
});
var btnCancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Cancel'
});
win.add(itemView);
win.orientationModes=[Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT];
win.open();
```

**MainScreen.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
win.title = 'My Window';

var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  backgroundColor:'red'
});

win.add(image);

var custbutton=Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'customer',
    top:200,
    bottom:300,
    left:90,
    height:'235',
    width:'235',
    backgroundColor:"#000"
});
custbutton.addEventListener('click',function alertingcustomer () {
    var newWindow1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title : "Customer screen",
        url:"CustomerScreen.js",
        title:'Window',
        backgroundColor:'#cccccc',
        modal:true
    });
   newWindow1.open(win,{animated:true}); 
});

win.add(custbutton);
```

**CustomerScreen.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
//Do stuff here
```

There are a lot of things you have to notice.

1. It is wrong approach include a file in another file and opening a window which has property url set to included file.
2. Opening a window multiple time is a wrong approach[You have written win.open() twice in the firts file, it is trying to open same window]
3. You're opening a window using url property, it'll be better to use [Ti.UI.currentWindow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow) property than creating a new window inside that.

Comment: Anand,Event is not fired , I tried with by writing alert message but not use.

Comment: No Anand,I added total code.Can you see it and suggest me where did I made mistake.

Comment: @rani: why you're trying to include the js file? While opening a new window from a url, the page will be loaded. Also try to change the code as custbutton.addEventListener('click',function() {
var newWindow1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        background : "#000",
        title : "",
        url:"Files/CustomerScreen.js"
    });
   newWindow1.open(win,{animated:true}); 
});. I'm not sure it will work. just try